# Slide down moreinfo div without using IDs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a box that is created without IDs.
I mean a box that slide out when I press on a button (also without IDs) and every other "moreinfo" text should not slide down.

Here is a example where I use IDs.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a[href*=#]').bind("click", function(e){ //Only a smooth scroll funtion
    var anchor = $(this);
    $('html, body').stop().animate({
      scrollTop: $(anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
    }, 1000);
    e.preventDefault();
  });
  return false;
});

//Here I must define every content box. And my goal is, that i need only one function.
$('#box1_more_btn').click(function() {
  if($('#box1_more').css('display') == 'none') {
    $('#box1_more_btn').text("less");
    $('#box1_more').slideDown(400);
  } else {
    $('#box1_more_btn').text("more");
    $('#box1_more').slideUp(400);
  }
});

$('#box2_more_btn').click(function() {
  if($('#box2_more').css('display') == 'none') {
    $('#box2_more_btn').text("less");
    $('#box2_more').slideDown(400);
  } else {
    $('#box2_more_btn').text("more");
    $('#box2_more').slideUp(400);
  }
});
```

```css
.moreinfo {
  display:none;
}

#box_1 {
  color: black;
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
}
#box1_more {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.008)
}

#box_2 {
  color: black;
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
}
#box2_more {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.008)
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div id="wrapper">
    <br /><br />

    <div id="box_1" class="box">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <h2 class="featurette-heading">This is a<span class="text-muted"> header</span></h2>
            <p class="lead">
              First box   ...    <a href="#box_1"><span id="box1_more_btn">more</span></a> !
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="container moreinfo" id="box1_more">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <h3>More Info</h3>
            This is the first more Info box<br /><br />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> <!-- BOX-1 end-->

    <br /><br /><br /><br />

    <div id="box_2" class="box">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <h2 class="featurette-heading">This is a<span class="text-muted"> header</span></h2>
            <p class="lead">
              Second box   ...    <a href="#box_2" id="box2_more_btn">more<!-- This Button should also rename--></a> !
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="box2_more" class="container moreinfo">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <h3>More Info</h3>
            This is the second more Info box<br /><br />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> <!-- BOX-2 end-->

  </div>

</body>
```

So I imagine it without IDs.
I tried that, but do not know how to go

This is my attemp without using IDs:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[href*=#]').bind("click", function(e){
      var anchor = $(this);
      $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: $(anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
      }, 1000);
      e.preventDefault();
    });
    return false;
  });

  //Here I must define every content box. And my goal is, that i need only one function.
  $('.morebtn').click(function() {
    if($('.moreinfo').css('display') == 'none') {
      $('.morebtn').html('<a href="#"> less </a>  '); // Is it possible too, that the window scroll down to "this" div?
      $('.box_moreinfo').slideDown(400);
    } else {
      $('.morebtn').html('<a href="#"> more </a>  ');
      $('.box_moreinfo').slideUp(400);
    }
  });
```

```css
.moreinfo {
       display:none;
}

.box {
  color: black;
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
}
.box_moreinfo {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.008)
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

  <div id="wrapper">
    <br /><br />

    <div class="box">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <h2 class="featurette-heading">This is a<span class="text-muted"> header</span></h2>
            <p class="lead">
              First box   ...    <span class="morebtn"><a href="#">more</a></span>  !
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="container moreinfo box_moreinfo">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <h3>More Info</h3>
            This is the first more Info box<br /><br />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> <!-- BOX-1 end-->

    <br /><br />Now, both boxes slideOut on click...<br /><br /><br />

    <div class="box">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <h2 class="featurette-heading">This is a<span class="text-muted"> header</span></h2>
            <p class="lead">
              First box   ...    <span class="morebtn"><a href="#">more</a></span>  !
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="container moreinfo box_moreinfo">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <h3>More Info</h3>
            This is the first more Info box<br /><br />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div><!-- BOX-2 end-->

  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at your markup you've made life quite difficult for yourself!

If this were something I was doing I'd make the relationship more explicit in the HTML:

```
<section class="has-more-info">

    <h1>Header</h1>

    <p>
      Text here... 
    </p>

    <button class="show-more-info">Show more</button>
    <div class="more-info hidden">
        <h3>More Info</h3>
        <p>This is the first more Info box</p>
    </div>

</section>
```

Then you could use:

```
$('.has-more-info').each( function() {
    $(this).find('.show-more-info').click( function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).siblings('.more-info').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

You need to style the .hidden class as display:none; initially, or onload so as to not impede non-JS users.

I haven't tested this but the concept should get you going.